# Error while running apache2ctl graceful

Tags: apache2, ssl

When I run this command: `sudo certbot --apache -d example2.com -d www.example2.com`

I get the following error:

```
Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
```

After having search and tested several solutions I could not found anything.

My guess is that the problem comes from certbot not understanding the config files of Apache2, because in my case it's maybe a little bit complicated, I want to use a different SSL certificate for two different sites, *example1.com* and *example2.com*.

Here is the virtualhosts in my apache2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example1.com
    ServerAlias www.example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Require all granted
        # Enable .htaccess overrides if required
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example1.com
    ServerAlias www.example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Require all granted
        # Enable .htaccess overrides if required
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on

</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example2.com
    ServerAlias www.example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html1

    <Directory /var/www/html1>
        Require all granted
        # Enable .htaccess overrides if required
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example2.com
    ServerAlias www.example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html1

    <Directory /var/www/html1>
        Require all granted
        # Enable .htaccess overrides if required
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And I don't if this can help but I also have:

in sites-available folder:

> example2.com-le-ssl.conf, example2.com.conf, default-ssl.conf, 000-default.conf

in sites-enabled folder:

> example2.com-le-ssl.conf, example2.com.conf, default-ssl.conf, 000-default.conf

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and I am using a vps

Thank you